# Creating a localhost subdomain redirects all localhost links

Tags: redirect, subdomain, localhost, wamp

I'm trying to setup a subdomain on localhost using Wamp. The subdomain i'm creating is store.localhost, now I can get that subdomain to work, but when I go to anything else with localhost in the url it redirects to store.localhost. So just http://localhost redirects to store.localhost.

My host file has the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.0.1 store.localhost
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf file has:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/store"
    ServerName store.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And i've uncommented the line in httpd.conf regarding virtual hosts.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another VirtualHost defined with ServerName localhost? If not, then Apache will use the first defined VirtualHost to handle the request, so you might want something like this

```
#catch all server
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/catchall"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

#store.localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/store"
    ServerName store.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

See the Apache manual section on [named based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) for more.

Comment: The only virtual host that is defined is the one for the store. So should I use exactly what you posted in the vhosts file? I just tried it and while store.localhost works I get a 404 for anything else.

Comment: Never mind, I seem to have gotten it to work. I just had the servername localhost block point to the www directory. Thanks for your help :)